# How to use loading ProgressBar with RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm developing an Android application which load data from Firebase Database in a RecyclerView. And ai notice that when network speed is low the recycler view doesn't show anything and take time to show data. So I want to use a loading progress bar with RecyclerView until RecyclerView is ready to show data.But I don't know how to do that and need help.

Comment: Please edit your question show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any code, so I answer your question based on my approach:

XML (We have a ConstraintLayout with RecyclerView and Progressbar)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In your java code (MainActivity):

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
recyclerView.viewTreeObserver
        .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                progressbar.visibility = View.GONE
                recyclerView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            }
        })
recyclerView.adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(yourItems)
```